# C# como fazer uma funcao string executar comando ativo?

Tags: c#, c, winforms, funções, visual-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em C# e estou presa num erro na hora de passar de um form pro outro. O form principal chama-se Main e o novo Form1... enfim...
Eu consigo enviar uma variavel string pro outro, mas ai ela nao executa nada alem de message box.

Form1 = enviando pro Main

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pid = ltBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string valor = ltBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    pid = pid.Substring(0, pid.IndexOf('-', 0));
    if (!pid.Equals(""))
    {
        Main destino = new Main();
        destino.funcao(valor);
        this.Hide();
    }


}
```

Main recebendo de forma inutil...

```
public void funcao(string valor) {
    MessageBox.Show("deu certo uhuuu sqn");
    label1.Text = valor;

}
```

Infelizmente eu consigo receber a mensagem de que deu certo, porem a label1 nao muda, e nada a mais que eu faça alem de messagebox parece funcionar... alguem pode da um help ai???

Comment: Você instanciou um novo objeto da classe `Main`, porém você não executou o método `destino.Show()` para mostrar o formulário.

Comment: falta colocar  .Show()

Comment: Mas entao, a Form1 é pra ser um formulario secundário, eu nao dei hide ao abrir outro

Answer (score 0):

Boa Noite,

Caso sua duvida foi de como passar uma parâmetro para outro formulário.
Você pode passar o parâmetro pelo construtor do formulário alvo.

Exemplo: 
//C#

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Codigo no formulario pai
        var frmMsg = new frmMensagem("Ola", "Mundo");
        frmMsg.ShowDialog();
    }
}

//Formulario Alvo.
public class frmMensagem {

    public frmMensagem(string parametroOla, string parametroMundo) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblOla.Text = parametroOla;
        lblMensagem.Text = parametroMundo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passe um `Array` de parâmetros, ou somente os parâmetros, que deseja instanciar a sua classe `Main` direto no construtor da mesma:

**1. Exemplo usando `Array` de parâmetros**

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pid = ltBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string valor = ltBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    pid = pid.Substring(0, pid.IndexOf('-', 0));
    if (!pid.Equals(""))
    {
        string[] parametros = {"Olá mundo!", "Foo Bar"};

        Main destino = new Main(parametros);
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

E então, faça isso no construtor de seu `Main.cs`:

```
public Main(string[] parametros) {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.label1.Text = parametros[0];   // Olá, mundo!
}
```

**2. Exemplo usando parâmetros diretamente como argumentos**

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pid = ltBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string valor = ltBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    pid = pid.Substring(0, pid.IndexOf('-', 0));
    if (!pid.Equals(""))
    {
        Main destino = new Main("Olá, mundo");
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

E então, faça isso no construtor de seu `Main.cs`:

```
public Main(string textoDoLabel) {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.label1.Text = textoDoLabel;   // Olá, mundo!
}
```

---

### Por que meu código não estava dando certo?

Você estava chamando o método `funcao` a partir de outro Thread de onde foi invocado o `Main`, e então, tentava alterar uma propriedade dentro da mesma. Isso é ilegal no .NET Framework, você precisa criar um Callback para alterar essa variável.

Se não quiser criar um callback, você pode deixar a propriedade [CheckForIllegalCrossThread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls?view=netframework-4.8) para `false` e logo desabilitar a verificação em runtime:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

E no final, não se esqueça do `Main.Show()`.